# Question for Conflict in insertion of data in DB by user and admin, see below for description

Tags: mysql, database

I have a case that what will happen when at one end Admin is editing the Details of user "A" in a table "users" and at the same time user "A" itself edits its details in table users. Whose effect will reflected.. And what can be done to make it specific to some one or to give the priority?

Thanks and Regards...

Comment: One who submits the data last is the one who takes the priority. Question is, why should any of them have the priority in the first place? Tampering with locking mechanisms can ruin the natural flow of app.

Comment: Thats what I need to know What is Locking in this???

Comment: And that's precisely what I'm trying to advocate against - you can research `LOCK` in MySQL at their documentation. Basically, you can `LOCK` the table if administrator is editing the user's data. However, what if: administrator closes the page without editing the data, meaning he just closes his browser window? Or his PC shuts down? What releases the lock then? You wait for a timeout? What if the admin has the page open for 12 hours and user can't edit their data because lock is in effect? Feature about locking the data for edit is bad, think about all cons and pros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Michael J.V. says, the last one wins - unless you have a locking mechanism, or build application logic to deal with this case.

Locking mechanisms tend to dramatically reduce the performance of your database. 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/internal-locking.html gives an overview of the options in MySQL. However, the scenario you describe - Admin accesses record, has a lock on that record until they modify the record - will cause all kinds of performance issues.

The alternative is to check for a "dirty" record prior to writing the record back. Pseudocode:

```
User finds record
Application stores (hash of) record in memory
User modifies copy of record
User instructs application to write record to database
Application retrieves current database state, compares to original
If identical
     write change to database
If not identical 
     notify user
```

In this model, the admin's change would trigger the "notify user" flow; your application may decide to stop the write, or force the user to refresh the record from the database prior to modifying it and trying again.

More code, but far less likely to cause performance/scalability issues.